# Calling model custom method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I'm trying to call a custom method I created in my model, in my controller but when I submit my form that points to the controller action, I get the following error:

> undefined method `add_manager' for #Rally:0x4c1fa90

```
def add_manager
    if @rally.add_manager(manager_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @rally, notice: 'Manager successfully added.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
```

Here is what I have in my code

**rally.rb**

```
def self.add_manager(params)
    user = User.where(:email => params[:email])
    rally.users << user
end
```

**rallies_controller.rb**

```
  def add_manager
    if @rally.add_manager(manager_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @rally, notice: 'Manager successfully added.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @rally.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Testing I've done so far:

- Check the @rally is set: works
- Checked listed methods available: add_manager was not listed
- Tested all commands in rails console: works

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using *self* in a method definition makes it a class method. As such, Rally.add_manager will work, but I doubt this is what you intend.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic I see. It's weird that it still works in rails console then but not in the controller. So would the best solution be to move it as a private method in the controller?

Comment: No, just remove *self* from the method definition. Also, are you sure that ```rally.users << user``` will fail if ```user``` is nil? If it doesn't, you're making a needless check.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic That worked! Thanks for the help. As for the check, I haven't added any yet. Just wanted to make sure I was able to process form properly before adding other bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class method:

```
def self.add_manager(params)
```

To an instance method:

```
def add_manager(params)
```

as @rally is an instance of your Rally class

*(answered in comments above - removing from unanswered list)*